# Adding an Array to an Array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Im trying to learn how to add arrays into arrays, I have the following code:

```
puts "would you like to save a data set"
response = gets.chomp

if response == "y"
  puts "create a new dataset?"
  create_data_set = gets.chomp
  while create_data_set == "y"
    puts "what do you want to name the data set?"
    dataset = gets.chomp
    dataset = Array.new
    puts 'would you like to add some grades to the array?'
    store_grades_response = gets.chomp
    while store_grades_response == "y"
        puts 'enter grade ->'
        grade = gets.chomp.to_i
        dataset << grade
        puts 'would you like to store another grade?'
        store_grades_response = gets.chomp
    end
    all_data_sets = Array.new
    all_data_sets.push(dataset)
    puts "would you like to create a new data set?"
    create_data_set = gets.chomp
  end
end

puts all_data_sets
```

Im basically asking a user to enter a array name which should create an array, add values to the array and if required by the user add some more arrays and values to it. At last the array should be added to an array. And then I'm trying to display all the arrays.

The code works fine, I'm looping through everything but when it `puts all_data_sets` It only shows the last array that was created? i would like to store all the arrays within the one array called `all_data_sets`

Comment: Something I noticed in your code. In your first `while` loop, you create a local variable `dataset` which is supposed to be a `string` representing the name a user wants for the **dataset** but then you reassign `dataset` to an `array` which essentially means the name the user chose is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new array `all_data_sets` at the end of each loop. One solution will be to have it before the loop.

```
puts "would you like to save a data set"
response = gets.chomp
all_data_sets = []
if response == "y"
  puts "create a new dataset?"
  create_data_set = gets.chomp
  while create_data_set == "y"
    puts "what do you want to name the data set?"
    dataset = gets.chomp
    dataset = Array.new
    puts 'would you like to add some grades to the array?'
    store_grades_response = gets.chomp
    while store_grades_response == "y"
        puts 'enter grade ->'
        grade = gets.chomp.to_i
        dataset << grade
        puts 'would you like to store another grade?'
        store_grades_response = gets.chomp
    end
    all_data_sets << dataset
    puts "would you like to create a new data set?"
    create_data_set = gets.chomp
  end
 end

puts all_data_sets
```

This way, you keep pushing the  `datasets` into the `all_data_sets` after each loop.

I hope this is explanatory enough.

Answer (score 0):

Fix

Its because your create new_data_sets array each time you do the loop, declare it outside enclosing while loop

Code

```
def main
    mainDataSet = [] # All datasets
    dataSetNames = [] # Incase you want to store data set names 

    response = getInput("Would you like to save a data set")

    if(response == "y")
        choice = getInput("Create a new dataset?")          
        while choice == "y"
            dataset = getInput("What do you want to name the data set?")
            dataSetNames << dataset
            dataset = []
            choice_2 = getInput("would you like to add some grades to the array?")
            while choice_2== "y"
                grade = getInput("Enter grade")
                dataset << grade
                choice_2 = getInput("Store another grade?")
            end
            mainDataSet << dataset

            choice = getInput("Create a new data set?")
        end
    end

    puts mainDataSet
    puts dataSetNames
end


def getInput(message)
    puts "#{message} -> "
    gets.chomp
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can concat, prepend or append arrays just like this

```
dataset.concat all_dataset
dataset + all_dataset
```

[Concat documentation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxmNSn5s3PAhUHuY8KHSppCogQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fruby-doc.org%2Fcore-1.9.2%2FString.html&usg=AFQjCNEm0o-ZVmyru52W6atj-0qARMfmwg&bvm=bv.135258522,d.c2I)

**prepend or append**

```
dataset.push(*all_dataset)
all_dataset.unshift(*dataset)
```

[Array stuffs](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcuc7B5s3PAhVJrI8KHXXFDzcQFghKMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fruby-doc.org%2Fcore-2.2.0%2FArray.html&usg=AFQjCNGReFWLSnfoqV0sHhqfHWc5gQSEIw&bvm=bv.135258522,d.c2I)

Also you can do slice and whole bunch of stuffs check at the ruby docs link